# Python Beautifulsoup4:

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to extract the sender and recipient addresses individually for this html table? I'm not having much luck digging through documentation on how to search for nested tags.. in other words i need to be like: `soupy.select('td[style="color: \#99999"]` and if content = SENDER.. then look at the next `<a>` tag and extract the content from that.' I dont even know how to articulate this lol.

```
      <td style="color: #999999;">SENDER:</td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <a class="uSearch" style="color: #000000" href="#" onclick="parent.eSearch('sender_match', 'match_is', 'sndr', 'sender@somedomain.com')">sender@somedomain.com</a>
      </td>

      <td style="color: #999999;">RECIPIENT:</td>
        <td>
          <a class="uSearch" style="color: #000000" href="#" onclick "parent.eSearch('recipient_match', 'match_is', 'rcpt', 'recipient@mydomain.com')">recipient@mydomain.com</a>
      </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate the `td` *by text* and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
sender = soup.find("td", text="SENDER:")
print(sender.find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True))
```

Note that you can go directly to the sender link by checking the `onclick` to contain "sender":

```
print(soup.select_one("a[onclick*=sender]").get_text(strip=True))
```